# Program to do fork exec while touching large memory regions

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork

I want to write some C code that has the following requirement:

1. Repeated fork exec.
2. The fork'ed process should use a large amount of memory and then either give it up or just die or I would just kill it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What?? Weird homework? Or you have some other purpose? What have you tried?

Comment: @Ivella this is not a homework. Haven't tried anything yet. I was just going to. I will post my code.

Comment: For what purpose do you need this? We might be able to provide a better solution if we knew the actual problem...

Comment: @thkala I am trying to test an older linux kernel 2.6.31 to test if the fork exec mechanism is stable enough. The problem is we cannot switch to a newer kernel and have to work with this version only. We have been seeing some weird things happening recently and the suspicion is that some fork exec patch might be required to fix some of the problems.

Comment: Uh, I don't want to sound condescending, but it's unlikely that any *weird* things that you are seeing are due to a bug to the fork/exec mechanism in the Linux kernel - that is one of the most heavily exercised subsystems...

Comment: How is it that you can *patch* your kernel but not switch to a newer one, anyway?

Comment: Maybe your process are simply being killed by the [OOM Killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer)?

Comment: fork/exec is pretty much how every single thing in UNIX works (ok, slight exaggeration) - if a simple C program could trigger an issue, I think you've got bigger problems (unless the program was designed to trigger a very specific flaw, but what you've described isn't that).  Also, remember when you've written that program, you'll still be restricted to any limits defined in the shell you run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned long long bytes;
    char bytes_str[32];
    void *buf;
    int i;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [megabytes]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else if (argc < 3) {
        switch (fork()) {
        case 0:  break;
        case -1: perror("fork");
                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        default: exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        bytes = strtoull(argv[1], 0, 0) * 1024 * 1024;
        snprintf(bytes_str, sizeof(bytes_str), "%llu", bytes);
        if (execlp(argv[0], argv[0], "child", bytes_str, (char *)0) != 0) {
            perror("execlp");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* NOT REACHED */
    } else {
        bytes = strtoull(argv[2], 0, 0);
    }
    if (bytes < 1024*1024) exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    buf = malloc(bytes);
    if (buf == 0) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memset(buf, '\xff', bytes);
    free(buf);
    bytes /= 2;
    snprintf(bytes_str, sizeof(bytes_str), "%llu", bytes);
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        switch (fork()) {
        case 0:  break;
        case -1: perror("fork");
                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        default: continue;
        }
        if (execlp(argv[0], argv[0], "child", bytes_str, (char *)0) != 0) {
            perror("execlp");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* NOT REACHED */
    }
    return 0;
}
```